# Thread Handler for methods class in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I read to following [post](https://rafalcieslak.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/c11-stdthreads-managed-by-a-designated-class/) in order to implemant a thread handler to pass a method class in a thread.

I would like to create a generic thread Handler from the one described in the article. 
So what I done was to just virtualize the method MainThread() and then implemant it in a class which inherits of the virtual class ThreadHandler (just like in python where you have to define a run() method which executes when you call Start())

```
class MyClass{
public:
  MyClass() : the_thread() {}
  ~MyClass(){}
  void Start(){
    the_thread = std::thread(&MyClass::ThreadMain,this);
  }
  virtual void ThreadMain() = 0 ; 
private:
  std::thread the_thread;

};
```

Thanks ! :D

When i run the following code :

```
class A : public MyClass {
private: ...
public:
 void Run(void) {
   std::cout << "Hi" ;
 };
int main() {
 A().Start()
 }
```

But it doesn't work : at the execution it tells me that a pure virtual method has been called.

I was thinking about a solution with templates something like that :

```
class ThreadHandler {
private:
std::thread the_thread ;
T* object ;
public:
void Start() {
        the_thread = std::thread(&T::Run, *object);
};
ThreadHandler(void) : the_thread() {};
~ThreadHandler(void) {};
};
```

An idea ?

Comment: Where is your definition of `ThreadMain()`?

Comment: Presumably you know you need to inherit from `MyClass` and override `ThreadMain` right?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the shown `MyClass` class. Since the question fails the "complete" requirement of a [mcve], no authoritative answer will be possible.

Comment: Your `while` loop is broken. It will create a new thread, then immediately create another one (without joining the first) which will call `std::terminate` because `the_thread.joinable()` is true.

Comment: Yes i know i need to inherit from MyClass and override ThreadMain().